# Progress Bar not Working in AJAX Form Output

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a simple ajax form. But Progress Bar doesn't work on ajax form output, it freezes. I have put an example on the page so you can see it working normally.
my goal is to be able to provide the code(progress bar) here in ajax output.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35985771/20310847

The problem here is, I believe there is a conflict/conflict between the script that checks the progress bar in the AJAX output and the ajax.  It appears then, when it finished, it disappear, but no visual progression on... I wonder what I need to do to make progress bar from Ajax Output look normal without freezing?

Form.htm

```html
<html>
<head>
    <!-- progress bar style  start -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
    .progress,
    .alert {margin: 8px;}   
    .alert {display: none;} 
    .alert-success {
        --bs-alert-color: #2c4238;
        --bs-alert-bg: #f8faff;
        --bs-alert-border-color: #768478;
        width: auto;
        max-width: max-content;
    }   
    @media screen and (max-width: 1568px) {
        .alert-success {
            width: auto;
            max-width: max-content;
        }
    }
    </style>
</head>
<!-- progress bar style  end -->

<body><br>
    <!-- form start -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js"></script>
    <form class="form" action="process.php" method="POST" name="checkaddress" id="checkaddress">
    <input type="text" name="v" /> </td><input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" /> 
    </form>
    <!-- form end -->
    
    <!-- ajax output div is here -->
    <div class="done"></div>
    
    <!-- Here is the progress code I want to reflect in the ajax output. start -->
    <br>====================================
    <br> Example: normally this code(progress bar) works below. but it doesn't work when I call the code with ajax. freezes as above.
    <br>
    <div class='progress col-md-7 ps-0 pe-0'>
        <div class='progress-bar' role='progressbar' aria-valuenow='60' aria-valuemin='0' aria-valuemax='100' style='width: 60%;'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='alert alert-success' role='alert'>hello xxxxx</div><br>
    <!-- end -->
    
    
    <!-- form ajax script start -->
    <script>
    $('#checkaddress').on('submit', function(e) {
        // get formdata in a variable that is passed to the ajax request
        var dataToPassToAjax = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: "process.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: dataToPassToAjax,
            cache: false,
            success: function(resultHtml) {
                // add the returned data to the .done element
                $('.done').html(resultHtml).fadeIn('slow');
            }
        });
        // cancel the default form submit
        return false;
    });
    </script>
    <!-- end -->
    
    <!-- progress bar script start -->
    <script>
    var $progress = $('.progress');
    var $progressBar = $('.progress-bar');
    var $alert = $('.alert');
    setTimeout(function() {
        $progressBar.css('width', '10%');
        setTimeout(function() {
            $progressBar.css('width', '30%');
            setTimeout(function() {
                $progressBar.css('width', '45%');
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $progressBar.css('width', '80%');
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $progressBar.css('width', '90%');
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            $progressBar.css('width', '95%');
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                $progressBar.css('width', '98%');
                                setTimeout(function() {
                                    $progressBar.css('width', '99%');
                                    setTimeout(function() {
                                        $progressBar.css('width', '100%');
                                        setTimeout(function() {
                                            $progress.css('display', 'none');
                                            $alert.css('display', 'block');
                                        }, 500); // WAIT 5 milliseconds
                                    }, 500); // WAIT 5 milliseconds
                                }, 800); // WAIT 5 milliseconds
                            }, 600); // WAIT 2 seconds
                        }, 700); // WAIT 1 seconds
                    }, 900);
                }, 600); // WAIT 2 seconds
            }, 400); // WAIT 1 seconds
        }, 700); // WAIT 1 seconds
    }, 800); // WAIT 1 second
    </script>
    <!-- progress bar script end -->
</body>
</html>
```

process.php

```
<?php 
$v= $_POST['v'];
echo "<div class='progress col-md-7 ps-0 pe-0'> 
<div class='progress-bar' role='progressbar' aria-valuenow='60' aria-valuemin='0' 
aria-valuemax='100' style='width: 60%;'></div>  
</div>
<div class='alert alert-success' role='alert'>hello $v</div>";
?>
```

Comment: your first `script` tag is at an invalid location in the document - it should be in the head or the body only. The same holds true for the actual HTMl content - where is the `body`?

Comment: it doesn't matter. If you save form.htm and open it normally, you will see that the progress bar works normally. but when I call the same code with ajax, the same code does not work in the output.

Comment: All the AJAX operation does after it succeeds is update the content of the `.done` element and then show that element.  It's not clear to me how that's even related to the "progress bar".  Can you provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?  (The AJAX operation can be changed to point to a different URL for public consumption, or even replaced entirely with a `setTimeout` that performs the same follow-up operation with a hard-coded known result.)

Comment: `"it doesn't matter"` - I'm not suggesting that the problem was caused by this invalid HTML, but problems do arise caused by sloppy coding that are not obvious - modern browsers are far more forgiving than they were way back.

Comment: ^--- agreed.  *Always start with structurally/syntactically valid code.*  If your markup is invalid, the browser could be changing it in any number of ways to "quietly correct" it so it can be displayed.  In which case you don't actually *know* what your HTML is, and all functionality is unknown/undefined.  Step 1 is to validate and correct your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript syntax/structure.

Comment: Thank you for your warnings. The issue here seems to be with the script that controls the progress bar in the AJAX output. I believe there is a conflict between the two. I sincerely apologize for the HTML layout issues, and I would be pleased to receive a solution-oriented response.

Comment: My goal is to be able to provide the code here in ajax output. https://stackoverflow.com/a/35985771/20310847

Comment: Your code would be a lot easier to debug if you fixed the [machine detectable errors](https://validator.w3.org/) and formatted it to avoid having 895 character long lines ([80 characters maximum is commonly considered a good guideline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276022/line-width-formatting-standard)).

Comment: You can see, now that the above has been formatted slightly that there is an error with the nesting of tags `strong(open) -> font(open) -> strong(close) -> span(open/close) -> font(close)`  ~ any Javascript trying to target that would struggle

Comment: Also never call anything submit in a form. It interferes with the submit event

Comment: You can tell `"how inexperienced and uninformed"` I am? Really - I'm glad you pointed out the folly of my ways to me and everyone else and I shall certainly `improve my knowledge`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your progress bar doesn't work in AJAX because when the page is first loaded, there's no progress bar to work with - it only appears after the AJAX call. Your progress bar script runs immediately when the page loads, and it tries to access `.progress`, `.progress-bar`, and `.alert` elements which don't exist yet, because they're only added to the page after the AJAX call.

To make it work, you should include the progress bar script into the `success` function of the AJAX call. This way, it will be called after the new elements are added to the page.

Here is the modified JavaScript code:

```js
$('#checkaddress').on('submit', function(e) {
    // get formdata in a variable that is passed to the ajax request
    var dataToPassToAjax = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: "process.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: dataToPassToAjax,
        cache: false,
        success: function(resultHtml) {
            // add the returned data to the .done element
            $('.done').html(resultHtml).fadeIn('slow');
            
            // run the progress bar script here
            var $progress = $('.progress');
            var $progressBar = $('.progress-bar');
            var $alert = $('.alert');
            setTimeout(function() {
                $progressBar.css('width', '10%');
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $progressBar.css('width', '30%');
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $progressBar.css('width', '45%');
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            $progressBar.css('width', '80%');
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                $progressBar.css('width', '90%');
                                setTimeout(function() {
                                    $progressBar.css('width', '95%');
                                    setTimeout(function() {
                                        $progressBar.css('width', '98%');
                                        setTimeout(function() {
                                            $progressBar.css('width', '99%');
                                            setTimeout(function() {
                                                $progressBar.css('width', '100%');
                                                setTimeout(function() {
                                                    $progress.css('display', 'none');
                                                    $alert.css('display', 'block');
                                                }, 500); // WAIT 5 milliseconds
                                            }, 500); // WAIT 5 milliseconds
                                        }, 800); // WAIT 5 milliseconds
                                    }, 600); // WAIT 2 seconds
                                }, 700); // WAIT 1 seconds
                            }, 900);
                        }, 600); // WAIT 2 seconds
                    }, 400); // WAIT 1 seconds
                }, 700); // WAIT 1 seconds
            }, 800); // WAIT 1 second
        }
    });
    // cancel the default form submit
    return false;
});
```

This should resolve your issue. The progress bar script now runs after the AJAX call is successful, and the new elements are added to the DOM, so it should be able to find and manipulate them as expected.

### Improvements

The current JavaScript code involves a lot of nested `setTimeout` functions which make it hard to read and maintain. We can simplify it with a more dynamic and modular approach.

Consider something like this:

```js
$('#checkaddress').on('submit', function(e) {
    // get formdata in a variable that is passed to the ajax request
    var dataToPassToAjax = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: "process.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: dataToPassToAjax,
        cache: false,
        success: function(resultHtml) {
            // add the returned data to the .done element
            $('.done').html(resultHtml).fadeIn('slow');
            
            // run the progress bar script here
            var $progress = $('.progress');
            var $progressBar = $('.progress-bar');
            var $alert = $('.alert');
            
            var width = 0;
            var increment = 10; // change the increment value to control the speed of the progress bar
            var interval = setInterval(function() {
                width = width + increment;
                if(width >= 100) { // when progress reaches 100, stop interval and show alert
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    $progress.css('display', 'none');
                    $alert.css('display', 'block');
                }
                $progressBar.css('width', width + '%');
            }, 800); // this value controls the delay between each increment
        }
    });
    // cancel the default form submit
    return false;
});
```

Here, the progress bar width increases by 10% every 800 milliseconds until it reaches 100%, at which point the interval is cleared and the alert is displayed.

This approach is a little bit less flexible than how I would recommend, but it is easier to understand. If you want to give it a try anyway, something like this is how I would personally implement it.

```js
async function delay(duration) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, duration));
}

async function updateProgressBar($progressBar, $progress, $alert, values) {
    for(let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        await delay(values[i].delay);
        $progressBar.css('width', `${values[i].width}%`);
    }
    $progress.css('display', 'none');
    $alert.css('display', 'block');
}

$('#checkaddress').on('submit', function(e) {
    // get formdata in a variable that is passed to the ajax request
    var dataToPassToAjax = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: "process.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: dataToPassToAjax,
        cache: false,
        success: function(resultHtml) {
            // add the returned data to the .done element
            $('.done').html(resultHtml).fadeIn('slow');
            
            // run the progress bar script here
            var $progress = $('.progress');
            var $progressBar = $('.progress-bar');
            var $alert = $('.alert');
            var values = [
                {width: 10, delay: 800},
                {width: 30, delay: 700},
                {width: 45, delay: 400},
                {width: 80, delay: 600},
                {width: 90, delay: 900},
                {width: 95, delay: 700},
                {width: 98, delay: 600},
                {width: 99, delay: 800},
                {width: 100, delay: 500}
            ];
            updateProgressBar($progressBar, $progress, $alert, values);
        }
    });
    // cancel the default form submit
    return false;
});
```

Don't worry about it if the second example is too hard to understand. Focus on getting you code working and try to keep an eye out for code duplication. Every time you are repeating a lot of code, there's probably a better way to do it. :)

Comment: Why would you run the progress bar AFTER the data was loaded? Why not start it on the click of the submit WHILE the data is loaded? And then fade in the DONE?

Comment: @mplungjan You are definitely right, I was too focussed on the issue in the question, but that approach makes way more sense. (I need to leave in a minute, I'll update it tomorrow morning or feel free to edit my answer. thanks for pointing it out!)

Comment: I have mentioned it in [my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76687495/295783)

Comment: After the data is loaded I need to initialize the progress bar. because I don't put a progress bar on every data. The code that @y.Gerbi gave worked without any problems and it worked for me a lot. thank you to him.

Answer (score 0):

You have `setTimeout(function() {` in the top level of a `<script>`.

This means that it triggers **when the script element is parsed**.

A small number of seconds later, all the timeouts have expired and that code is finished.

Some time after that the user clicks the submit button which triggers the Ajax code which adds the `.progress` element to the page and fades it in:

> ```
> $('.done').html( resultHtml ).fadeIn('slow');
> ```

If you want the code which modifies that HTML to run **then** you have to put it **there**.

Answer (score 0):

1. I suggest preventDefault() to stop the form from being submitted rather than return false. If there is an error before the return false is hit, then the form WILL submit too

   ```
   $('#checkaddress').on('submit', function(e) { 
     e.preventDefault(); // stop the submission
     progress(0); /* my code */`
     /* rest of your code */
   ```
2. Your progress bar starts at 60%
3. You need to call the progress bar at submit time
4. Here is a MUCH drier (DRY: Don't Repeat Yourself) progress code

https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/r1hsom07/

I also suggest you fade in the done in the end of the progress bar.

```js
let $progress = $('.progress'),
 $progressBar = $('.progress-bar'),
 $alert = $('.alert'),
 steps = [
  { percent:  '10%', delay: 800}, 
  { percent:  '30%', delay: 700}, 
  { percent:  '45%', delay: 400}, 
  { percent:  '80%', delay: 600}, 
  { percent:  '90%', delay: 900}, 
  { percent:  '95%', delay: 700}, 
  { percent:  '98%', delay: 600}, 
  { percent:  '99%', delay: 800}, 
  { percent: '100%', delay: 500}, 
  { percent: 'none', delay: 500} 
];


const progress = i => {
  if (i >= steps.length) return;
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (steps[i].percent === 'none') {
      $progress.css('display', 'none');
      $alert.css('display', 'block');
    } else {
      $progressBar.css('width', steps[i].percent);
    }
    progress(i + 1);
  }, steps[i].delay);
}
progress(0); // Start (move this to your ajax)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div class='progress col-md-7 ps-0 pe-0'>
        <div class='progress-bar' role='progressbar' aria-valuenow='60' aria-valuemin='0' aria-valuemax='100' style='width: 0%;'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='alert alert-success' role='alert'>hello xxxxx</div><br>
```