# Recursively identifying lines which are longer than 80 characters in Emacs

Tags: emacs, coding-style

Since [it may be a good idea to have lines that are not wider than 80 characters in code files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110928/is-there-a-valid-reason-for-enforcing-a-maximum-width-of-80-characters-in-a-code), what's the most effective way of recursively identify these lines in an existing project using Emacs?

**UPDATE:**

Using Trey's suggestion, I'm currently using the following code:

```
(defun find-long-lines (base-dir)
  "Recursively look for lines longer than 80 characters files"
  (interactive "DPath:")
  (grep-compute-defaults)
  (rgrep "^................................................................................." "*" base-dir))
```

Which works fine in combination with **whitespace-mode**.

Comment: Not a complete solution, but `occur` expects a regular expression so you can use `occur` to identify lines longer than 80 chars and they'll be displayed in a nice buffer where you can click on them and Emacs will automatically jump over to the corresponding line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`igrep-find`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/igrep.el) and use a regular expression that matches 81(+) characters like so:

```
M-x igrep-find ^.................................................................................. RET /path/to/area/to/search/* RET
```

And then you get a buffer in compilation mode that lets you easily jump to each of the offending lines (either via a mouse click, or <kbd>C-x `</kbd> or <kbd>M-x next-error</kbd>).

Alternatively, you could use the built-in [M-x grep-find](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Grep-Searching.html) and use the same regular expression.

To enter 81 `.`, type <kbd>C-u 81 .</kbd>.

And, if you want to have this all contained in a single command (that prompts you for the path to the files), you can use this:

```
(defun find-lines-longer-than-80 (files)
  "Recursively look for lines longer than 80 characters files"
  (interactive (list (igrep-read-files)))
  (igrep igrep-program "^................................................................................." files igrep-options))
```

There are some other tips available on the Emacs Wiki for [Find Long Lines](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FindLongLines), including several options for highlighting lines that are longer than 80 characters when you're visiting a file.

Comment: And to enter the 81 dots, you can type `ESC 8 1 .` or `C-u 8 1 .`

Comment: @Giles I should have mentioned that, it's exactly what I did.

Comment: Thanks for this. Using the whitespace-mode for current buffers and it works like a charme. Your solution doesn't recursively go through all subfolders, does it?

Comment: I've updated my question. That code seems to work fine. Thanks a lot for your suggestions.

Comment: @RobertoAloi The solution does go through all the subfolders (that's the `-find` part of `igrep-find` and `grep-find`.  You can limit it to just a single folder by using the `igrep` or `grep` commands.

Answer (score 4):

I can't top EMACS specific solutions, but you can alter the command a bit to include file names (and type less).

```
rgrep "^.\{81\}" . -n (include line numbers)


rgrep "^.\{81\}" . -c (summary view per file)
```

Quotes not necessary for interactive rgrep prompt.

rgrep `RET` ^.{81} `RET` file-type `RET` path