# Visual Studio Interactive Console Width

Tags: python, anaconda, visual-studio-2017

Is there a way to increase the usable width of this console ? Currently any output gets wrapped at about 80 chars, and I don't see any option to change that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean the C# Interactive Window, one way to solve the issue is to drag the console off of the Visual Studio window and cause it to become its own window, like so:
[image: Widening actual console]

The other way is to use the zoom control in the bottom left hand corner of the console to reduce the font size, like so:

[image: Using zoom to increase character count]

However, [you should program assuming that the window will be 80 characters wide](https://stackoverflow.com/q/110928/4808244).

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but neither of those worked for me, the display width is always the same. This is the Python (Anaconda) window btw.